# Do they mean parallel instead of perpendicular?

Tags: solution-verification, vectors

*This question came in the admission exam of Rajshahi University in 2020-21*

Q) If two vectors $2\hat{i}+3\hat{j}+\hat{k}$ and $-4\hat{i}-6\hat{j}-\lambda\hat{k}$ are mutually perpendicular, then what will be the value of $\lambda$?

(A) 2

(B) -2

(C) 0.5

(D) -0.5

None of the options seem correct. The correct value of $\lambda$ will be -26 if the two vectors are perpendicular. Do they mean parallel? If the two vectors are parallel, then the value of $\lambda$ will be (A).

Comment: It does indeed seem like "parallel" was intended. Note that even the use of "mutually" (regardless of "parallel" or "perpendicular") is a bit unusual in the context of just two vectors. There may well be some kind of editing error. Alternatively, maybe there was an error in giving the vectors or the answer options. We can only speculate. ... Since the exam is quite recent, why not contact the University's math department directly and ask for clarification?

Comment: For fun, you could check the previous (and/or subsequent) admission exams for similarly-worded questions. Maybe it'll become clear that the above comes from a recycled template that was modified but perhaps not closely proofread. (These things happen.)

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic  Perpendicular :$\lambda=-26$ , parallel :$\lambda=2$

Comment: For safety  Option (D) should be given  non of the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two vectors are perpendicular, then:

\begin{equation*}
 -8-18-\lambda =(2,3,1) \cdot (-4,-6,-\lambda) = 0
\end{equation*}

Therefore, $\lambda = -26$.

If the two vectors are parallel, then:

\begin{equation*}
(-3\lambda+6,2\lambda -4,0) =(2,3,1) \times (-4,-6,-\lambda) = (0,0,0)
\end{equation*}

Therefore, $\lambda = 2$. What you claim is most likely correct.